# How can i display a list of images on top of the image that i recognized using arcore?

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore

Problem statement: I have a book cover, now i use Android phone to recognize that cover once the cover has been recognized. I should show me images of the pages inside the book. These page images are stored in internal storage.
I want to use ARcore for this. I have successfully made the sceneform model where i can display these images.
I am aware that the question is too vague but please direct me to a direction where i can implement this
I have successfully made the customArFragment

```
public class CustomArFragment extends ArFragment {
    @Override
    protected Config getSessionConfiguration(Session session) {
        Config config = new Config(session);
        config.setUpdateMode(Config.UpdateMode.LATEST_CAMERA_IMAGE);
        AugmentedImageDatabase aid = new AugmentedImageDatabase(session);
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_launcher_background);
        aid.addImage("image",image);
        config.setAugmentedImageDatabase(aid);
        this.getArSceneView().setupSession(session);
        return super.getSessionConfiguration(session);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) super.onCreateView(inflater,container,savedInstanceState);
        getPlaneDiscoveryController().hide();
        getPlaneDiscoveryController().setInstructionView(null);

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```